# Update timestamp when data update but don't update timestamp on updating post reach count

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP, I'm new in this line.
I have a table in database in which following rows occurs:
`ID`, `Title`, `Story`, `PostReach`, `DatenTime`
In which `ID` is primary and `DatenTime` is TimeStamp and on_update_current_timetemp
When I am updating data in a rows timestamp is updating, that's ok! 
But when a visitor visits a post and `PostReach` is update the timwstamp is also updating, how can I prevent this timestamp updating `PostReach` value.

Comment: Please post some of your working/non-working code before you start receiving downvotes.

Comment: Just let your code handle if you need to update your field or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Before update` trigger for this porpose. Update Timestamp manually by alike trigger. Disable automatic set of `DatenTime`. The idea is that it will set the `DatenTime` only if title or story have been changed or set from/to NULL. You can add other fields that (should they have been changed) will cause `DatenTime` to be set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. You need to consider setting `DatenTime` when you insert a new record.

```
BEGIN
IF ((OLD.title!=NEW.title)OR(OLD.story!=NEW.story)
OR
(ISNULL(NEW.title)XOR(ISNULL(OLD.title)))
OR
(ISNULL(NEW.story)XOR(ISNULL(OLD.story)))

THEN
SET NEW.DatenTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END IF;
END
```